# generating empty xml from schema

Tags: xml, xsd

I'm generating an empty xml from user specified xml schema but i have confused with namespace declarations on attributes.

For example for this schema;

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
           xmlns="http://tempuri.org/Product" 
           targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/Product">
    <xs:complexType name="ProductType">
        <xs:sequence>            
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="Id" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:attribute name="Name" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:element name="Product" type="ProductType" />
</xs:schema>
```

I have generated the this;

```
<root>
  <Product xmlns="http://tempuri.org/Product" 
           xmlns:ns1="http://tempuri.org/Product" 
           ns1:Id="1" 
           ns1:Name="2" />
</root>
```

But visual studio generating this;

```
<root>
  <Product xmlns="http://tempuri.org/Product" 
           Id="1" 
           Name="2" />
</root>
```

Which one is correct ?

**Update 1:**

Whatever xml schema **form** attribute is set to, if I load the generated xml in XML DOM, Name attribute NamespaceURI is always empty string. (While product has namespace)

I'm performing xpath queries on these attributes and I cannot decide between should I always use namespace prefix or assume it is always same with parent element's namespace.

Example difference;

```
/*/ns1:Product/@Id
/*/ns1:Product/ns1:@Id
```

What is common use case for namespaced attribute syntax (qualified ?, unqualified ?) without knowing schema ?

Answer (score 1):

The latter is correct, as the schema does not specify `attributeFormDefault="qualified"` on the root `<xs:schema>` element.  The default behaviour (`attributeFormDefault="unqualified"`) is that `<xs:attribute>` declarations that are nested inside a complex type have no namespace.  If it were set to `qualified` they would take the `targetNamespace` of the schema, at which point your first alternative would be correct.

Answer (score 0):

According to [sec. 3.2.2](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#declare-attribute) of the XSD 1.0 spec, or [sec. 3.2.2.2](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/#dcl.att.local) of XSD 1.1, local attribute declarations (like those for the `Id` and `Name` attributes in your example) are namespace-qualified if

- Their `xsd:attribute` declaration has `form="qualified"`, or
- Their `xsd:attribute` declaration has no `form` attribute, and the enclosing `xsd:schema` element has `attributeFormDefault="qualified"`.

Otherwise they are unqualified (their expanded name has a null namespace value).

(Note that XSD 1.0 provides the XML-to-schema-component mappings for both top-level and local attribute declarations in the same section; you have to be careful to check which case is being described.  XSD 1.1 subdivides the text more finely, to try to reduce confusion.)

So given the schema you show, it is the second instance, not the first, that is valid against the schema.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is about `form` attribute on xs:attribute element. If the `from` attribute value is `qualified` that the attribute described by the schema needs to be prefixed (i.e. belong to the namespace) otherwise it must not be prefixed. If the `form` attribute is missing then the value comes from `attributeFormDefault` on the xs:schema element. This attribute has the default value of `unqualified` if it is not specified. Go to [Xsd schema spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/) and search for 'attributeFormDefault' for all the details. I would say VS is right in this case.